# Removing the first character in a row *only if it's a number (Google Sheets / Excel)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data structured like so:

```
example
1test
test345
0moreexamples61
```

My question is; what formula should I use to delete the first character *only if it's a number (the numbers at the end ar fine). Thus:

```
1test > test
0moreexamples61 > moreexamples61
```

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following formula, which will work both in Google Sheets and in Excel:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)
```

The `ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1)))` term will check if the first letter. If it is a number, it will evaluate to `True`.

If it is `True`, the term `RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)` will take all text except the first letter and return it in the cell.

[image: Remove first character if it is a number in Gogole sheets or Excel]

Comment: Here is the same formula for the french users: `=SI(ESTNUM(CNUM(GAUCHE(A1;1)));DROITE(A1;NBCAR(A1)-1);A1)`

Answer (score 0):

In Sheets you can use [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)

```cpp
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^\d",)
```

[image]